# How to close main class for stopService

Tags: java, android

I want to close my class for `stopService();` , and i am using this method but i know that it's false , please help me:

```
if (Main_Page.this.finish() == true){
stopService(svc);
}
```

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
 stopService(new Intent(this,yourservice.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stop your service .. then do that in onDestroy() call back of your activity

```
public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
 stopService(svc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but when i used onDestroy svc cannot resolved to a variable.

Comment: you should use stopService(this,yourservice.class);

Comment: yup.. you should use stopService(this,yourservice.class) but remember a service can only be stopped if the stopping the service with the same context, with which you started it .